# EF Core include only sub property from entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.1

I need to map a relational entity to an endpoint, however I'm really struggling with it.

You see, the following `json` object is what I'm currently getting with my code, and it has the information I need, however it is very convoluted, I only need an array of `Cursos` which is a property of the `CursoUnidade` object.

```
"cursos": [
{
  "cuuCurId": 1,
  "curso": {
    "curId": 1,
    "curDescricao": "Analise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas",
    "curStatus": "A",
    "curCodExterno": "",
    "curObservacao": ""
  },
  "cuuUniId": 1,
  "cuuStatus": "A"
},
{
  "cuuCurId": 2,
  "curso": {
    "curId": 2,
    "curDescricao": "Engenharia Elétrica",
    "curStatus": "A",
    "curCodExterno": "",
    "curObservacao": ""
  },
  "cuuUniId": 1,
  "cuuStatus": "A"
}
]
```

What I need is something like this:

```
"cursos": [
{
    "curId": 1,
    "curDescricao": "Analise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas",
    "curStatus": "A",
    "curCodExterno": "",
    "curObservacao": ""
},
{
    "curId": 2,
    "curDescricao": "Engenharia Elétrica",
    "curStatus": "A",
    "curCodExterno": "",
    "curObservacao": ""
}
]
```

This is the Snippet responsible for the object I'm currently getting.

```
public IEnumerable<Unidade> GetCursosByUnidade()
{
    return _contexto.Unidade
                    .Include(c => c.cursos)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Curso)
                    .ToList();
}
```

I wish to know if how can I map the `Cursos` property directly instead of mapping it of a sub property of the entity?

I also tried doing it like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Unidade> GetCursosByUnidade()
{
    return _contexto.Unidade
                    .Include(c => c.cursos.Curso)
                    // .ThenInclude(c => c.Curso)
                    .ToList();
}
```

However this code throws the following error:

> Services/DataManager/UnidadeService.cs(107,40): error CS1061: '"ICollection" does not contain a definition for "Curso" and it was not possible to find an extension method "Curso" that accepts the first argument with the type "ICollection" (Maybe there is an use directive or reference in assembly missing?)[/Users/jed/Projects/Core/SVNSchool/School.csproj]

Comment: Can you please **translate** that error message into English?

Comment: I have translated it.

Comment: You're asking to change the type of the `CursoUnidade.Cursos` property, so you'll either need to project to an anonymous type or create a new class for this purpose and convert the `CursoUnidade` results to objects of this new class

Comment: Looks like you need `_contexto.Unidade.SelectMany(c => c.cursos)`.